# Reading inputs doesn't fill double array completely

Tags: c, arrays, double

I am trying to write a program that reads doubles that are stored in 2 different arrays, add them and print out the 2 arrays added together. I am trying to test my code but as I fill the arrays the prints show me that it doesnt fill the array after the first index is passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double arrayA[5];
    double arrayB[5];
    double arrayC[5];

    printf("Enter 5 doubles for array A\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        scanf("%lf", arrayA);
        printf("%lf\n", arrayA[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter 5 doubles for array B\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        scanf("%lf", arrayB);
        printf("%lf\n", arrayB[i]);
    }

    printf("Here are the two arrays added together\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        arrayC[i] = arrayA[i] + arrayB[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        //printf("%lf\n", arrayA[i]);
        //printf("%lf\n", arrayB[i]);
        printf("%lf\n", arrayC[i]);
    }


}
```

this is the output that i get in console for the first array

```
Enter 5 doubles for array A
1
1
1.000000
2
2
0.000000
3
3
0.000000
4
4
0.000000
5
5
0.000000
```

Comment: `scanf("%lf", arrayA);`??? Did you mean `scanf("%lf", &arrayA[i]);`?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%lf", arrayA)` always reads in into the first element of `arrayA`, whereas
`printf("%lf\n", arrayA[i])` prints the `i`'th element. So you are accessing an uninitialized part of an array, which yields undefined behaviour. Use `scanf("%lf", &arrayA[i])` (and equivalent for `arrayB`).